# Co-mingling Service Fabric programming models in the same environment

Tags: azure, microservices, cross-platform, azure-service-fabric

Can containers, guest executables, and reliable services be installed and operate together in the same Azure or on-premise Service Fabric environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each service does have its own programming model. In fact, if you take a look at the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-containers-overview#scenarios-for-using-containers) it is one of the scenario's:

> **Mix containers and Service Fabric microservices:** Use an existing container image for part of your application. For example, you might use the NGINX container for the web front end of your application and stateful services for the more intensive back-end computation.

Another official statement, if you need it, can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-scenarios#design-applications-composed-of-stateless-and-stateful-microservices) in the docs as well:

> Design applications composed of stateless and stateful microservices

As it is written, applications consists of one or more services, each service has its own programming model and it is up to you to decide what is best for a given service.

Comment: Peter - Thank you for your help and this answer. I obviously missed the "Mix containers and..." paragraph as I searched the documentation (or more likely glossed over it). This answers my original question. I also read through the second reference you cited which doesn't actually address my question. This is more of a microservices application design options comparison page that seems to favor stateful microservices.